# QT file chooser filter bug?

Tags: qt, debian, xfce

Since upgrading from Debian 10 to Debian 11, all of the computers in my lab now have a bug when opening files in most programs (inkscape, xfburn, audacity, etc.). I believe this is the QT file chooser/picker being presented by all of these different programs, but I may be wrong in that assumption.

When I select File->Open, then start typing to filter down the files, the filter applies, then the file list goes blank. Each time I type the next letter, the filtered files show for a split second before disappearing again.

[image]

Are others dealing with this? Any ideas on a fix?

*5.10.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.70-1 (2021-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux, XFCE*

Comment: What you see is the native filepicker from the OS, not the Qt one.

Comment: Would that be Thunar in my case? Because the Thunar file manager looks quite a bit different. Typing a file name in the file manager doesn't filter down the list but instead just jumps your selection down to what you've typed.

Comment: I've found that this issue only occurs for LDAP users, not for local users.